# How to perform count in access across three tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

I am having a three tables, for a sake of simplicity let's say 
Category (1...many) Topic (1...many) Post

What I am trying to achieve is to get a CategoryID and a total number of topics in this category as well as the total number of posts.

The best result what I made was using the following query:

```
SELECT category.ID, COUNT(topic.id) AS topiccount, COUNT(post.id) AS postcount
FROM ((category)
 LEFT JOIN topic  ON topic.categoryid = category.id)
 LEFT JOIN post ON post.topicid = topic.id
GROUP BY category.id
```

Unfortunately, even if I have just a 6 topics in the table associated with a category I am getting '7' as a result. 
I did some research on it and it seems that I have to use a DISTINCT keyword inside a COUNT however access does not support it and I could not find appropriate way to do it in the subqueries.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get one more record, because you are not counting the topics, you are actually counting the topic-post joined records. Use the following :

```
SELECT category.id, count(topic.id), Nz(Sum(numofposts),0)
FROM (category LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT topic.id, count(post.id) as numofposts, topic.categoryId
    FROM topic LEFT JOIN post on topic.id = post.topicId
    GROUP BY topic.id, topic.categoryId
) as TP ON category.id=TP.categoryid)
GROUP BY category.id
```

The `Nz` is there to ensure that in empty topics you don't get Null sums